# Is it possible to replace the Windows boot manager with GRUB without having Linux installed?

Tags: boot, windows, grub

It's pretty much all in the header. I'm about to get a new PC and I'm planning on installing Windows on it, but I would like to know if it would be possible to get GRUB on there without a dual-boot.

EDIT: I would like to make it clear that I would like to *only* boot to GRUB, not boot to GRUB which then redirects me to `bootmgr`.

Comment: AFAIK, GRUB can only chainload the windows bootmanager (and not boot the windows kernel itself). At least it's not the default way it's done. But of course you can have GRUB without a linux distro installed on your PC. You can install GRUB with a live USB/CD.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a "manual" install from a LiveCD, I think

- Boot a live CD, execute `fdisk -l | grep EFI`, note the partition number
- mount that somewhere
- add a folder hierarchy similar to this

`/boot/efi# find EFI/debian/ -ls
drwx------   2 root     root         1024 Jun 27  2019 EFI/debian/
-rwx------   1 root     root      1533296 Aug  1 13:02 EFI/debian/grubx64.efi
-rwx------   1 root     root      1322936 Aug  1 13:02 EFI/debian/shimx64.efi
-rwx------   1 root     root      1261192 Aug  1 13:02 EFI/debian/mmx64.efi
-rwx------   1 root     root      1206824 Aug  1 13:02 EFI/debian/fbx64.efi
-rwx------   1 root     root          127 Aug  1 13:02 EFI/debian/grub.cfg
-rwx------   1 root     root          108 Aug  1 13:02 EFI/debian/BOOTX64.CSV`

Get the files from the grub project site, edit the grub.cfg to your liking.
On next boot, it should be one of your options

**Alternative way**: If the live-CD has grub installed, or if you can get it installed in that environment, you can just issue `grub-install /dev/sdProbablyA` from a normal shell in that LiveCD environment.

Comment: I tried using the alternative way in a WinXP VM, and when I issued `grub-install`, it told me that it didn't recognize the filesystem. Of course, this is probably because I'm trying to install GRUB to an NTFS drive, but is there any way around it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.G As GRUB is a stand-alone boot loader and can be installed onto a computer that doesn't have Linux installed, to boot those operating systems that are installed. It is also used in other OSes as *BSD family.

In order to achieve it you can either download grub itself and run the install procedure from the grub shell:

```
# grub-install /dev/sdX
```

where X is you driver.
For a complete reference:
https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall.html

Comment: So then how do I get it to install over `bootmgr`? Do I just install it to my System Reserved partition?

Comment: No you install it on the beginning of your windows partition. The system reserved partition USUALLY is your windows image backup.